# Facebook messenger flask обрабатывает сообщения только создателя страницы

Tags: python, flask, facebook, messenger

Делаю бота для отправки сообщений из мессенджера публичной страницы фб в телеграм и обратно, используя flask и ngrok. Как мне сначала показалось, все работало: бот присылал автоответы, пересылал вопросы в телеграм чат, ответы пересылались обратно, все ок. Но до тех пор, пока не написал первый клиент.

В общем проблема в том, что бот обрабатывает сообщения только от владельца страницы (меня), от любого другого пользователя нет никакой реакции. Пробовал разные варианты, в том числе и готовые чат-боты из простых гайдов. Максимально упростил код, чтобы просто проверить, есть ли реакция, и результат тот же. На сообщения с основной страницы есть реакция, на остальные нет:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def foo():
    print("SUCCESS")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно чтобы приложение прошло проверку и получило необходимые права, надо было внимательнее читать то, что написано в отделе для разработчиков ФБ